# batch regex the output of reg query command to a variable

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, registry, dword

**summary**

I need to be able to find the DWORD value of a registry key and set a variable to it to run an if statement against it.

how can i grab just the dword of a reg query so that i can work with it in the rest of my script?

**reg query**

```
reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall
```

**req query output**

```
EnableFirewall    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

**what i need to grab**

`0x1`

**pseudo code**

```
query firewall reg value
regex out DWORD value and set to variable var1
if var1 == 0x1 then do blah
else do other blah
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall') do set "var=%%b"
if "%var%"=="0x1" (do this) else do that
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall') do set FWSTATUS=%%x
```

If testing from the command line, change the `%%x` to `%x` instead.