# Batch file command to query numerical value of registry entry

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to get my install batch file to only run if the current version I'm installing is newer than the version installed on the local machine (if installed at all). I've been looking around and it seems like the common approach is to write to the registry, and then use that entry to key off for the future, by checking to see if it's there and the value.

I found this [FOR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412150/batch-regex-the-output-of-reg-query-command-to-a-variable) here on this site that will check to see if a registry key equals a particular value, but I want the query to be able to determine if the registry value is less than a specified value. Is HKLM......\Installed_Reg_Key value (which is 4.5) less than 5.0. If I have to have two IF statements, one to check to see if the key is there (if it's not currently installed) and another to check to see if it's less than what I'm pushing, that's fine. And if I have to write a particular type of reg key, I could care less.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: if you populate a key with the date in a format like yyyymmdd then it is a very simple command to compare greater or less than.  If you are likely to release more than once a day then add the HH hour to the end of the string above.

Answer (score 1):

See code below -

You just need a single FOR statement to test - as it will populate an environment variable.  If the variable does not exist, then the program is not installed, and you :CALL an appropriate action.

The code below:

1. Queries the registry for the value in HKLM\software\Batchver\batchver
2. Assigns it to an environment variable.
3. Tests if assignment was successful.  If assignment fails (ie no data in registry entry), call the installation routine.
4. Three more statements test the value of the environment variable, and take action each time.
5. All subroutines contain a routine to update the registry to the current version number.

> @echo off
>       SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
>       SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
>       set batchver=
>
> ```
> for /f "tokens=3 skip=3" %%i in ('reg query HKLM\Software\batchver /v batchver') do @set batchver=%%i
>
>
> if .batchver==. call :new_install
>
> :: if already installed do nothing.
>
> if batchver==5.0 @echo Up to date!  && goto :exit
>
> if batchver leq 4.5 call :reinstall
>
> if batchver gte 4.6 call :patch
>
>
>
> goto :exit
>
>
> :new_install
>
>   <new installation routines here.>
>   ::update registry with new version
>   reg add HKLM\software\batchver /v batchver /d 5.0 /f
>
>
> goto :eof
>
> :reinstall
>   <reinstall routine here>
> ::update registry with new version
>   reg add HKLM\software\batchver /v batchver /d 5.0 /f
> goto :eof
>
> :patch
>   <patch routines here>
> ::update registry with new version
>   reg add HKLM\software\batchver /v batchver /d 5.0 /f
> goto :eof
>
> :exit
> ```

Comment: Your compare will be ascii in nature and not numeric, because of the period.

Comment: That is correct.  But, it turns out that 4.6 is still greater than 4.5 in an ascii compare.

Comment: Thanks, will try this in the next few days when I have some time. If I wanted to expand the lookup to more than 3 digits (4.55 or 4.5.5), do I just need to change the "tokens=3 skip=3" to either 4 or 5?

Comment: Looks like three digits still evaluate correctly - 4.5.4 is less than 4.5.5, so your approach should be ok, and the code above will work with these types of version numbers..  The skip=3 means skip the first 3 lines of output from the reg.exe command in the FOR loop.